# Setting an id issue in d3

Tags: javascript, casting, d3.js

So this is what I'm doing:

```
selection = canvas.selectAll("circle").data(mydata)

            selection.enter().append("circle")

            selection
                .attr("id", function(d, i){ var result = i+''; return result; })
```

In short, I'm trying to set the id of each element to be a string representation of its index.

However, when I try to access that particular element later by using `d3.select("#1")` or by using a number variable i and going `d3.select("#" + i.toString())`, nothing seems to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 56):

I figured it out, apparently ids can't start with a number.

Comment: Ugh thank goodness somebody said that, would have taken me ages to realise!

Comment: You just saved me so much time.