# D3.js How to identify a single bar uniquely within a group bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created group bar chart by using D3.js. Each group has 2 bars. When any bar is clicked it must show some data using custom alert box. Now the bar can click and it shows data.

```js
var state = svg.selectAll(".TestSuite")
         .data(data)
         .enter().append("g")
         .attr("class", "TestSuite")
         .on("click", function(d,i) {
                if(i==0){
                Alert.render(d3.select(this).data()[0].FalseStatements);
                }else{
                 Alert.render(d3.select(this).data()[0].TrueStatements);
                }
            })
         .attr("transform", function (d) {
         return "translate(" + x0(d.TestSuite) + ",0)";
     });
```

But data is vary according to clicked bars. So how to identify each single bar within a single group uniquely.

Here "if condition" that I used does not do the thing I want.How do I correct it?

Thank you.

(Suppose one group of bar consists two bars, one shows true count and other shows false count for a particular scenario. When we click the bar which shows true count then it should appear "TrueStatements" which is already have in data.using `d3.select(this).data()[0].TrueStatements` can do this. And also when someone click the bar which shows false count then it should appear "FalseStatements" which is already have in data.using `d3.select(this).data()[0].FalseStatements` can do this. My question is how do we identify the bar which shows true count and the bar which shows false count uniquely for do this task.)

EDITED:

How I get the data for bar chart(This is inside a for loop)

```js
originalDataSetForBarChart.push({
          TestSuite: "TS"+treeIndex,
          Pass: trueAppear,
          Fail: falseAppear,
          FalseStatements : falseStatement,
          TrueStatements : trueStatement
     });
```

Bar chart code

```js
 var margin = {
     top: 20,
     right: 10,
     bottom: 30,
     left: 40
 },
      
 width = 890 - margin.left - margin.right,
      
 height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

 var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
     .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .5);

 var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

 var y = d3.scale.linear()
     .range([height, 0]);

 var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
     .range(["#4169E1", "#800080"]);

 var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
     .scale(x0)
     .orient("bottom");

 var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
     .scale(y)
     .orient("left")
     .tickFormat(d3.format(""));
    
    
 var w = width + margin.left + margin.right;
    
 var h = height + margin.top + margin.bottom;
  
 var svg = d3.select(".chart1").append("svg")
           .attr("width", w)
           .attr("height", h)
           .append("g")
           .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//svg.call(tip);

var xg = svg.append("g")
     .attr("class", "x axis")
     .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");

 var yg = svg.append("g")
     .attr("class", "y axis");

 yg.append("text")
     .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
     .attr("y", 6)
     .attr("dy", ".71em")
     .style("text-anchor", "end")
     .text("Count");
```

I append bars to this chart inside a setInterval function using following method.

```js
function update() {
     startTime_barChart = new Date().getTime();
     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         var testSuite = d3.keys(data[i]).filter(function (key) {
             return key !== "TestSuite";
         });

     }

     data.forEach(function (d) {
         d.trueFalseCount = testSuite.map(function (name) {
             return {
                 name: name,
                 value: +d[name]
             };
         });

     });

     x0.domain(data.map(function (d) {
         return d.TestSuite;
     }));
     x1.domain(testSuite).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
     y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
         return d3.max(d.trueFalseCount, function (d) {
             return d.value;
         });
     })]);
      
     //making the x axis/y axis
     xg.call(xAxis);
     yg.call(yAxis);
      
     //removing all the rectangles
     svg.selectAll(".TestSuite").remove();
    var tip_word; 
    var tip = d3.tip()
        .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
        .offset([-10, 0])
        .html(function(d) {
            tip_word= "<strong style='color:white'>"+
                            "Pass count :"+
                      "</strong>"+
                     " <span style='color:white'>" + d.True + 
                      "</span></br>"+
                     "<strong style='color:white'>"+
                            "Fail count :"+
                      "</strong>"+
                     " <span style='color:white'>" + d.False + 
                      "</span>";
            return word;
        });
    
     var state = svg.selectAll(".TestSuite")
         .data(data)
         .enter().append("g")
         .attr("class", "TestSuite")
         .on("click", function(d,i) {
                if(i%2 == 0){//How to set this condition
                  
                Alert.render(d3.select(this).data()[0].FalseStatements);
                }else{
                    
                 Alert.render(d3.select(this).data()[0].TrueStatements);
                }
               
            })
         .attr("transform", function (d) {
         return "translate(" + x0(d.TestSuite) + ",0)";
     });
    
    svg.call(tip);
     
     state.selectAll("rect")
         .data(function (d) {
         return d.trueFalseCount;})
         .enter().append("rect")
         .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
         .attr("x", function (d) {
         return x1(d.name);
     })
         .attr("y", function (d) {
         return y(d.value);
     })
         .attr("height", function (d) {
         return height - y(d.value);
     })
         .style("fill", function (d) {
         return color(d.name);
     });
 
      
  if(barChartLegentController==1){    
   var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(testSuite.slice().reverse())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

   legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

   legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });
      
  barChartLegentController=2;      
  }
    
  endTime_barChart = new Date().getTime();
  var totalbar = (endTime_barChart-startTime_barChart)/1000;     
  //alert('Total bar time : '+ totalbar+' seconds');
 }
```

Comment: The click event callback can take two arguments, the first corresponding to the data bound to the clicked element. Try something like ˋ.on("click",function(d,i) {  console.log(d);     })` and see if this is the data you're looking for

Comment: @Hugues Stefanski - I edit my question little bit more. ˋ.on("click",function(d,i) { console.log(d); })` contain data what I need to show, but how to identifing bars uniquely?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you are asking yet but the best way to identifying any element/entity is with an id, something like the following:

`d3.select(this).attr(id, function(d, i) {return 'bar_' + i});`

Add this inside the iterative function where you are creating your bars. In this way you will be able to select them from anywhere in your code with a `d3.select('#bar_1)`.

If you only want to identify each bar it would be something like this:

```
var state = svg.selectAll(".TestSuite")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("id", function(d,i) {return 'bar_' + i})
  .attr("class", "TestSuite")
  .on("click", function(d,i) {
    if(i==0){
      Alert.render(d3.select(this).data()[0].FalseStatements);
    }else{
      Alert.render(d3.select(this).data()[0].TrueStatements);
    }
  })
  .attr("transform", function (d) {
    return "translate(" + x0(d.TestSuite) + ",0)";
});
```

In the case that you would like to identify each bar with an Id related to its contents (true or false statements) I would suggest something like the following:

```
var state = svg.selectAll(".TestSuite")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "TestSuite")
  .on("click", function(d,i) {
    var barId;
    if(i==0){
      barId = 'falseBar_' + i;
      Alert.render(d3.select(this).data()[0].FalseStatements);
    }else{
      barId = 'trueBar_' + i;
      Alert.render(d3.select(this).data()[0].TrueStatements);
    }
    d3.select(this).attr('id', barId);
  })
  .attr("transform", function (d) {
    return "translate(" + x0(d.TestSuite) + ",0)";
});
```

In any case, this will assign an unique Id to every bar (i.e. "bar_25" or "falseBar_14") to each bar, giving you an ideal way to identify each bar.

EDIT: After OP showed me the actual code they are working with, the following are my suggestions for a solution (which are actually on the same lines as the code above).

The code you should actually be tinkering with is the one below the code you posted. It is where the actual bars are rendered:

```
state.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
.enter().append("rect")
  .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.name); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
```

My suggestion to add an id attribute to each bar would be the following:

```
state.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
.enter().append("rect")
  .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
  .attr("id", function(d, i) {return 'bar_' + i}) // <-- Edited line
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.name); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
```

It is important that you understand why this, and not the code block you provided initially, is the pertinent one. As you well said, the first block renders each group of bars (hence the `append("g")` which stands for svg group). The second block starts with a `append("rect")` which means svg rectangle. This and other lines (i.e. style("fill")..., attr("x")... and attr("y")...) clearly give away that this block is the one dealing with the actual bars and not the groups.

Comment: Can you tell me that what you mean by id in given code?

Comment: @DesiDelite Yes, every element may contain an 'id' attribute so it can be uniquely identified. It is important to not assign it to any other element again in your code. Here is another good example on how to use them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188395/setting-an-id-issue-in-d3
What I meant with my answer (and I apologize if I wasn't explicit enough) is that id's main case use is exactly the problem you are presenting us here, which is the need to uniquely identify an element.

Comment: @DesiDelite my last edit shows what your code should look like.

Comment: Here i value belongs to one group. http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051 in this example CA is one group, it has 7 bars, CA-->i=0, TX-->i=1,...so on. then the way you talk set same id for all bars in one group, isn't it? I'm really sorry, But still i can't understand,help me to solve this.

Comment: @DesiDelite Don't worry, we will. Now that I see your example I get it better. I didn't know that each 'i' represented a whole group, and reading the code provided in your URL you can see that the piece of code you gave in your question is related to (as you said in the above comment) to each **group** of bars. The block of code below it addresses each individual bar, the one starting with state.selectAll("rect"). My newly edited answer should illustrate to you my suggestions.

Comment: @DesiDelite I just edited the question again to answer your question, hopefully this time it will help you with your problem.